# Tippero usage instructions

Tags: tipping, tippero, user-guide, irc

Is there a Tippero user guide? Where can I find a list of Tippero commands?

Specifically, how can I:

- Give a Monero tip to one person on Reddit?
- Give a Monero tip to everyone currently active on the #Monero IRC channel?
- Check my Monero Tippero balance?
- Deposit to, or withdraw from, my Tippero account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To tip one person on Reddit you can reply to someone's comment and use the command: !tip 'nick' 'amount'

To do a rain tip (for everyone currently active on the #monero IRC channel) you can use the command: !rain 'amount' 'users'

You can check your Monero Tippero balance by using the !balance command on either IRC or Reddit.

Lastly to deposit or withdraw from your Tippero account you can use the commands !withdraw and !deposit, which will bring up the relevant information for you to fill in.

Also remember that on IRC you can use the !help command to pull up a list of command modules.  Same goes on Reddit if you message /u/tippero with the command !help in the message body :)

Answer (score 7):

Tippero contains its own instructions, which can be queries with the `!help` and `!commands` commands (send a message to the bot with this command). The latter gives you a list of modules and their commands. To view a one liner description of what each command does, try `!commands NAME`, replaving NAME with the module you want, eg `!commands dice`.

The canonical tip command is `!tip thisnick 1.1`, which tips thisnick 1.1 monero, but Reddit also has a more convenient syntax: `+2.5 /u/tippero`, which will tip the author of the comment you're replying to.

If you're going to use IRC and Reddit, you may want to link your Freenode and Reddit Tippero accounts, so you can use a single balance: see `!linking_accounts`, which will explain how to do so.

Last, for each of your specific questions:

- Tip someone with `!tip NICK AMOUNT`
- Tip everyone in a channel with `!rain AMOUNT`
- See your balance with `!balance`
- Deposit information is available via `!deposit` (don't forget to use the payment id this gives you), and withdraw with `!withdraw ADDRESS`